# Excel add values based on conditions and distinction

Tags: excel

everyone!

I have a question regarding a calculation I am trying to achieve in Excel. From the example picture, I have testing numbers for State level but not county level. On April 11th, 2020, Illinois had 273 tests conducted throughout the State, Michigan with 108, and California with 361. The calculation I am trying to figure out is the column labeled "Country Tests". I want a formula that I can drag down a column which will give me a sum of tests conducted in all States for the particular date in the first column i.e. for April 12th, 2020, I want 1157 for all rows with April 12th, 2020 date and US as country.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na3Mf.png)

I appreciate all the help.

Thank you!

Comment: Research `SUMIFS`.

Answer (score 0):

As BigBen mentioned try using `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(J:J;A:A;A2;B:B;"US")
```

with `A:A` containing the date, `B:B` the Country. Instead of `"US"` you can simply use `B2`, in this case the formula works for different countries.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but it seems to do the job !
[Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cml8B.png)

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.